# Peewee - How to Convert a Dict into a Model

Tags: python, peewee

Lets say I have

```
import peewee

class Foo(Model):
    name = CharField()
```

I would like to do the following:

```
f = {id:1, name:"bar"}
foo = Foo.create_from_dict(f)
```

Is this native in Peewee? I was unable to spot anything in the [source code](https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/blob/master/peewee.py).

I've wrote this function which works but would rather use the native function if it exists:

```
#clazz is a string for the name of the Model, i.e. 'Foo'
def model_from_dict(clazz, dictionary):
     #convert the string into the actual model class
    clazz = reduce(getattr, clazz.split("."), sys.modules[__name__])
    model = clazz()
    for key in dictionary.keys():
    #set the attributes of the model
        model.__dict__['_data'][key] = dictionary[key]
    return model
```

I have a web page that displays all the `foo`s and allows the user to edit them. I would like to be able to pass a JSON string to the controller, where I would convert it to a dict and then make Foos out of it, so I can update as necessary.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you have a dict, you can simply:

```
class User(Model):
    name = CharField()
    email = CharField()

d = {'name': 'Charlie', 'email': 'foo@bar.com'}
User.create(**d)
```

Comment: what if the keys in the dict (`d`) are not in the model yet? Will this still work?

Answer (score -2):

You could use [PickledKeyStore](http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html#PickledKeyStore) which allows you to save any value as a python dict and it works like [Python's pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) library.