# Peewee - Update an entry with a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, peewee

I found [this handy answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22750439/peewee-how-to-convert-a-dict-into-a-model) on how to **create** a new table entry using a dictionary.

Now i'd like to **update** an entry with the same method. but i don't know how to adress the specific table entry that i'd like to update.

My current version looks like this:

```
entries = Fruit.select().order_by(Fruit.name.desc())
#... all entries are listed with the index number
entry_index = int(input("Please enter entry number: "))
#...
entry_index -= 1

name = "Banana"
color = "yellow"

if input('Update entry? [Yn] ').lower() != 'n':
        entries[entry_index].name = name
        entries[entry_index].color = color
```

As you can see i adress every field explicitly.
I would like to put the variables (name, color) in a dictionary and update the entry at position "entry_index" with the fore-mentioned double-star-shortcut [like in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22750439/peewee-how-to-convert-a-dict-into-a-model).
But i can't find a [proper method in the docs](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#updating-existing-records).

Does anyone know how to accomplish that?

Thanks for your help!

Muff

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To update an object, you can:

```
entry = entries_index[idx]
entry.something = 'new value'
entry.another_thing = 'another thing'
entry.save()
```

Alternatively:

```
Entry.update(**{'something': 'new value', 'another_thing': 'another'}).where(Entry.id == entry.id).execute()
```

All of this is covered in the [docs](https://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/query_examples.html?highlight=update#update-some-existing-data), please give them a thorough read. Follow the [quick-start](https://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/quickstart.html) step by step and I think you will have a clearer idea of how to use peewee.

Comment: Just wondering, what would the expected behavior be in the situation where the dictionary contains a name/value pair that is NOT found in the model?  Would it simply be ignored?

Answer (score 6):

The double star shortcut is a python thing. It allows you to expand a dictionary into key-word arguments in a method. That means you can do something like this:

```
fruit = { "name": "Banana", "color": "yellow"}
some_method(**fruit)
```

which would be the equivelent of doing:

```
some_method(name="Banana", color="yellow")
```

I don't think that's helpful to you here though. You've already updated the values on the selected entry and all you need to do next is save them.

[According to the peewee docs](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#updating-existing-records), once you have created an instance, any calls to save will cause that instance to be updated. That means you only need to call the `save` method to update the values you've changed. If you add a final `entries[entry_index].save()`, that should persist those changes.